# How to use different drums from Ableton Live when playing on a Roland TD-11?

Tags: ableton-live, electronic-drumset

How to use different drums from Ableton Live when playing on a Roland TD-11? I have downloaded the driver and I can now record when I play the drums, but I can only use the drum racks included in the original Roland.